# Changing MQTT username (ACCESS_TOKEN) dynamically?

Tags: mqtt, access-token, thingsboard

I want to push ThingsBoard's incoming telemetry data to another ThingsBoard server, so I add MQTT rule node in root rule chain to make it, like the following picture.
[image: ThingsBoard flow]

when I configure the parameters of the MQTT rule node, like the following picture.
[image: node configuration]

The username is required by ThingsBoard MQTT connection, if I use a static ACCESS_TOKEN,everything is OK, but I want to use a dynamic ACCESS_TOKEN (as username) to specify which device to receive the MQTT data.

I have try the following variables in username parameter, but failed!
`${msg.metadata.credentials}`

what shall I do ?